# Can using a different cpu cause the output of the same program to be different?

Tags: deterministic, non-deterministic

Should the same program always output the same result, if it does not use any random numbers or I/O, or is it possible that it will output something different on a different cpu (but same architecture, no need for recompile) ? I'm specially thinking about calculations with floats and doubles which depend heavilly on precision, as used in numerical approximations.

Comment: The question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/968435/what-could-cause-a-deterministic-process-to-generate-floating-point-errors?rq=1 seems to give a negative answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it should ever happen, since CPUs using the same architecture should basically use the same set of registers that they use for storing data.

Short: The result will be the same.