# Floating point numbers do not work as expected

Tags: c, floating-point

In the code below when i give input as 1 10 2 1 2 2, sum is printed as 52 and sum3 as 31.200001 whereas it shld have been 31.200000

```
int main(){

    int t,n,i,a[2000],m,j,f;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--){
        scanf("%d",&n);
        scanf("%d",&f);
        for(i=0;i<f;i++){
            scanf("%d",&a[i]);
        }
        scanf("%d",&m);
        if(n!=0){
            int sum=n*(n+1)/2;
            int sum2=0;
            for(j=0;j<i;j++){
                sum2+=a[j];
            }
            sum-=sum2;
            printf("%d\n",sum);
            float sum3;
            if(n%2==0) sum3=(1.0-2.0*m/n)*sum;
            else sum3=(1.0-2.0*m/(n+1))*sum;
            printf("%f\n",sum3);
        }
        else printf("0.0000\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Floating point inaccuracy examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples)

Comment: Don't use `float` for floating point numbers without a good reason: use `double` instead. "The teacher told us to use `float`" is **NOT** a good reason to use `float` before trying to persuade her otherwise; if she insists ... oh well ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the Floating-Point Guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/):

> **Why don’t my numbers, like 0.1 + 0.2 add up to a nice round 0.3, and
>   instead I get a weird result like 0.30000000000000004?**
>
> Because internally, computers use a format (binary floating-point)
>   that cannot accurately represent a number like 0.1, 0.2 or 0.3 at all.
>
> When the code is compiled or interpreted, your “0.1” is already
>   rounded to the nearest number in that format, which results in a small
>   rounding error even before the calculation happens.

Answer (score 2):

The decimal number 31.2 is not representable as a binary fraction. To be more specific, the nearest value of type `float` is `31.200000762939453125` which is exactly 8178893 * 2<sup>-18</sup>.

If you need a number that is closer to the decimal 31.2, consider using the type `double`, where your result would be `31.199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875` or 8782019273372467 * 2<sup>-48</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This is the nature of `float`s.  They are not guaranteed to be perfectly accurate.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328622/how-deterministic-is-floating-point-inaccuracy) for more detail on how/why this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

31.2 is not a representable number in binary floating-point.  No matter what calculation is used to produce it, you will never get a float which is exactly equal to 31.2.  The answer you got is about as good as you can reasonably expect.

Answer (score 0):

.. But you can try to reduce this possibility. You need to take into account of the exponents for addition/subtraction amongst other things.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
    `printf("%g\n",sum3);`
instead of 
    `printf("%f\n",sum3);`
in your code to get proper output..

I hope it will work.